# chroot into a Linux with X window system installed, from a Linux without X window system, and then run xinit, there is no mouse and keyboard working

Tags: mount, x11, chroot, xinit

I have two systems on my machine. One is Ubuntu and the other one is Linux from scratch (LFS) which I built it my self.

Ubuntu has X window system installed but LFS has no windowing system whatsoever.

I `chroot` from LFS (/dev/sda3) to Ubuntu (/dev/sda1) root partition with following commands:

```
mkdir /mnt/sda1
mount -v              /dev/sda1    /mnt/sda1
mount -v --bind       /dev         /mnt/sda1/dev
mount -vt devpts      devpts       /mnt/sda1/dev/pts -o gid=5,mode=620
mount -vt proc        proc         /mnt/sda1/proc
mount -vt sysfs       sysfs        /mnt/sda1/sys
mount -vt tmpfs       tmpfs        /mnt/sda1/run
chroot /dev/sda1
```

Then after `chrooting`, I ran `xinit`. X window system started but apparently without detecting mouse.

Currently I'm stuck in X window system and I cannot do anything. When I press `ctrl+alt+F1 to F6` or `ctrl+alt+backspace` nothing happens. To complicate matters further, before I `chroot`, I was compiling something on another `console tty` and I don't want to lose that compilation progress with pushing hardware restart button.

Is there a way out of this situation.

Comment: Can you post the X server log ?

Comment: I don't have access to that system any more, I wish I could see the log now

Answer (score 1):

Some people have reported you need to bind-mount udev too.

Comment: Oh, right, i always forget this site has several kind of posts.. should have made it a comment I guess.

Comment: Do you know where `udev` is located on root file-system?

Comment: Sorry, it's actually /dev, which you already have bind-mounted. I didn't see that. I guess I should just remove this answer.